# Restrict List View to Role (SP O365)

Tags: office-365, list-view

​How do I restrict a list's View access by user roles?  I have a list with multiple Views (one per country).  Each view restricts columns (country-specific) and filters rows based on country.  I want to restrict the view to the respective country roles that I have created.  I will give only one role to each user.  So, when the user opens the list, he/she should see ONLY the view he/she is assigned to.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. View is not a security trimmed feature (ie like SQL view tables) What you could do is to have multiple folders in the list and then brake the inheritance per folder so when user goes to list it just see folder he has rights to. For admins and staff that has access to all items you can create 'flat' view that will show all items without folders.

Comment: Thanks for the note, Marek.  I haven't tried using folders within a list, ever before, and am not sure how they would be behave in "Datasheet" view.  Anyhow, I am going to play around with this and come back.  Meanwhile, any pointers to a guide on how to use folders in a list?  It would be a great help if you can.  Thanks.

Comment: They will work fine in datasheet view.  Remember that this is just a place holder. Customer will only see their folder and you can specify different view inside of the folder (only classic site this feature for some reason doesn't work in the modern sites). To enable folder in the library just go to the list settings--> advanced settings and make new folder command available to true. If you need some additional metadata in the folder you can create your own folder content type with additional columns  (to add it you will need to change allow management of content types in same settings page)

Comment: Please remember to mark as answer.

Comment: You set me on the right course, Marek!  I am using this article to take the work further: <https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782>